# NSIS installer and Crystal Reports runtime

Tags: crystal-reports, nsis

I have a .Net WinForms application which uses Crystal Reports and I would like to create an installer which also installs the Crystal Reports runtime (CRforVS_redist_install_32bit_13_0_9.msi).

Has anyone experience or an example script which installs the runtime correctly and silently?

What are the parameters for the msi file for a silent install? (easy question)
How can I determine in my NSIS script, if CR is already installed (hard question)

Comment: And what does this .zip file contain? Are there no documents with recommendations on how to install these dependency's?

Answer (score 0):

I have good experience with following code, for installing .msi silently in NSIS:

```
nsExec::ExecToLog "msiexec /passive /i $MsiFilePath"
```

This is working fine for me (e.g. for SQLSysClrTypes.msi), but i don't have tried this for Crystal Reports.